# CSS animating based on position around radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate the circles shown in the figure below in an "Explosion" sort of way so they leave their current positions outside of the view port.

The problem is, I need them to move in a linear position from their current location so that they're hidden once they "explode".

These circles are generated with jQuery based on radius and count, I can catch them in a for loop using the below:

```
function explodeFields() {
    var fields = $('.field');
    fields.each(function() {
        self = $(this);
        console.log(self.attr('id'));
    });
}
```

I need all fields to move towards the viewport based on their current position. So fields marked as "1" for example should move to the right side of the screen horizontally, while field "13" in the upper circle should go up and slightly to the right while "Exploding".

Appreciate the help!
Thanks.[image]

### EDIT

I'm using a library called movejs which helps with css transitions etc... I would appreciate a way to do this using CSS only if possible.
This is what an element looks like in the DOM:

`<div id="field-inner2" class="field field-inner" style="left: 357px; top: 320px;">2</div>`

### EDIT 2

This is the JS:

```
 function distributeFields(radius, name) {
        var radius = radius;
        var fields = $('.field-'+ name), container = $('#container'),
            width = container.width(), height = container.height(),
            angle = 0, step = (2*Math.PI) / fields.length;
        fields.each(function() {
            var x = Math.round(width/2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width()/2);
            var y = Math.round(height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height()/2);
            if(window.console) {
                console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
            }
            $(this).css({
                left: x + 'px',
                top: y + 'px',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
            });
            angle += step;
        });        
    }
    
    function explodeFields() {
        var fields = $('.field');
        fields.each(function() {
            self = $(this);
            $(self).addClass('move');
        });
    }
```

And the CSS:

```
#container { 
    width: 600px; 
    height: 600px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    position: relative; 
}

#center { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 250px; 
    top: 250px; 
    background: #000;
    @include border-radius(50%);
}

.field { 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 
    position: absolute; 
    background: #f00; 
    @include border-radius(50%);
    @include transform(translateX(50px));
}

.move {
    @include animation-name(move);
    @include animation-duration(3s);
}

@include keyframes(move) {
    0% {
        @include transform(translateX(50px));
    }
    100% {
        @include transform(translateX(200px));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation should be possible to achieve using pure CSS. But to set it up and trigger the animation I assume it's ok to use JS?

If so, one way to solve it would be to have an element ("circle-wrapper") with a circle element as a child. The circle moves horisontally to the right. By duplicating "circle-wrapper" and rotating each one you can get something like what you describe.

JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    var ang = (i / 10) * 360;
    $('<div/>')
        .addClass('circle-wrapper')
        .append($('<div/>').addClass('red-circle'))
        .css({
           transform: 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)'
        })
        .appendTo($('body'));
}

// trigger anim
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.red-circle').addClass('move');
});
```

CSS:

```
.black-circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 250px;
    top: 150px;
}
.circle-wrapper {
    transform-origin: 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 260px;
    top: 160px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.red-circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
.move {
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otn0zmb6/1/

In the example, circle-wrapper has been given a width and a border to easier understand what's going on. Also, the button will only trigger the animation once (since the move class is not removed).

Comment: I am getting these values in the console style -> animation-name: move;
animation-duration: 3s; with a strikethrough like they're not being applied when i add the class. Do you have any idea why this might be happening? There is nothing overriding these values.

Comment: Also please take a look at my edit since I can't change the structure of the DOM.

Comment: It's probably because of missing browser vendor prefixes (-webkit, -moz, -ms). I didn't add them all, it works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize you couldn't change the DOM. I think it should be possible to give each field-inner the correct transorm and then add an additional css class. The rotation for each field-inner would have to be calculated based on the position between itself and the black circle.

Comment: I did, they all move to the same direction. Please check my edit. :)